# Finding 3 highest numbers in html data table and marking them red

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

Problem description:

I have data coming in that shows the electricity consumption of various buildings. These are in the form of html tables and may, and probably will, contain duplicates.

Using jQuery, how do I pick out the 3 highest numbers and mark them by making the background red?

Note: it's the three individually highest numbers that I want highlighted/marked red.

So if the in-data for example gives me 190, 180, 180, 170, 150 etc. I would like to highlight 190, 180 IN ONE PLACE/CELL, and 170.

Also, I wish to treat the tables as if I have only read-rights, not changing the table in any way except for the highlighting of the three highest numbers.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have some code? We're not here to write your code.

Comment: I have a code, just a lot of trouble posting it here due to format.

Answer (score 0):

Psuedo code:

```
var high = [],
    done = 0,
    final = [];
$("td").each(function(){
    high.push({ cell : $(this), val : parseInt($(this).text())});
});

// Now we got all cells sorted DESC
high.sort(function(a, b){
    return b.val - a.val;
});

for(var i=0;i<high.length &&  done < 3;i++){ 
    // Max highest 3
    if( $.inArray(high[i].val, final) == -1 ) {
        final.push(high[i].val);
        done++;
    }
    high[i].cell.addClass("red");
}
```

**Alternative psuedo code**

```
var final = [],
    done = 0,
    items = $("td").sort(function(a, b){
        return parseInt($(b).text()) - parseInt($(a).val());
    });

items.each(function(){
    var val = parseInt($(this).val());
    if( $.inArray(val), final) == -1 ) {
        done++;
        final.push(val);
    }
    if( done == 3 ) {
        return false; // Stop after we got enough
    }
    $(this).addClass("red");
});
```